# Updating child element classes when table row is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, toggleclass, uniform

I have a table of product options, each `tr` is one option. One is selected by default, to select another, a radio button must be checked before the form is submitted. This is easy enough but the entire `tr` must be clickable and check the radio button accordingly.

I *think* I've managed to get this to work using the script below:

```
$('.product-options tr').click(function() {
    $(this).find('td input[type=radio]').prop('checked', true);
});
```

In addition to this I also need to add a class of `.selected` to the `tr`. I tried with the following code but I also need to check if another `tr` already has a class of `.selected` and remove it.

```
$('.product-options tr').click(function() {
    $(this).find('td input[type=radio]').prop('checked', true);
    $(this).toggleClass('selected', true);
});
```

Obviously this will only toggle the class if you click the same radio button. This is where my limited javascript knowledge falls down. Can anyone help?

Finally, I also use a plugin called uniform.js which allows, selects/radio/checkboxes to be fully customisable. As this wraps a div then a span around the radio input a class of `.checked` is added to the span to toggle the checked/unchecked styling. This only changes if you click directly on the input. So I'll also need to factor in a similar bit of script to the `tr.selected` class for when any part of the `tr` is clicked, the custom radio button also has an updated class.

For reference mark-up for the javascript generated radio is:

```
<div class="radio">
    <span>
        <input type="radio" name="" />
    </span>
</div>
```

EDIT: Here's a CodePen with uniform.js included which should demonstrate the issue(s) better:

http://codepen.io/moy/pen/yeGRmO

Thanks, really hope someone can help with this. It *seemed* simple enough ...but as it's 'layered up', I'm a bit lost! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly you can simply access the siblings of the tr and put the checked radio on false.

```
$('.product-options tr').click(function() {
    $(this).find('td input[type=radio]').prop('checked', true);
    $(this).toggleClass('selected', true);
    $(this).siblings().find('td input[type=radio]').prop('checked', false);
    $(this).siblings().removeClass('selected');
});
```

This should find all radios and put them all on false, except for the row you clicked on.

**UPDATE**

To work with uniform, you can call `$.uniform.update()` directly when changing properties.

```
$(function() {
    $('input[type="radio"]').uniform();

    $('.product-options tr').click(function() {
        var tr = $(this),
            radio = tr.find('td input[type=radio]'),
            siblings = tr.siblings(),
            otherRadios = siblings.find('td input[type=radio]');

        tr.addClass('selected');
        siblings.toggleClass('selected', false);

        $.uniform.update(radio.prop('checked', true));
        $.uniform.update(otherRadios.prop('checked', false));
    });
});
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/tive/b6Lg31mr/)

Comment: Thanks, I tried that but unfortunately it doesn't remove the class of `selected` from the previously selected `tr` if another is clicked. Also the radio is wrapped in div's for styling. So the 'checked' status works but it also needs to add a class to it's parents so 'checked' styling is visible.

Comment: Check the demo, as I was just gonna update that part.

Comment: The uniform radios normally update themselves, no?
If not an additional `radio.closest('.radio')` can provide a class on his parent. Similar with `$.each()` for the other radios to clear the class.

Comment: Yeah they do if you click on the element directly but not when the table row is clicked. Must go off click rather than the status of the radio?

Comment: Ah, right => `.trigger('click')` should help, I'll update the demo.

Comment: updated the code, with a working uniform example. So this should be similar to your setup.

Comment: Nice one, I wasn't if people would be familiar with uniform. That gets the selected style to work on the row and checks to `input` but uniform class doesn't update - having a bit of a play now!

Comment: Spot on! Must of just submitted that last comment just after you did yours. That looks like it works great! Thanks a lot for you help Tim :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('.product-options tr').click(function () {
            $(this).find('td input[type=radio]').prop('checked', true);
            $(this).closest('table').find('tr.selected').find('span.checked').removeClass('checked');
            $(this).closest('table').find('tr.selected').removeClass('selected');
            $(this).addClass('selected'); $(this).find('td:last').find('span').addClass('checked');
        });
```

[Check This Link](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xZMxgY)

Comment: Thanks, I couldn't get this to work but I've added a CodePen if it helps: http://codepen.io/moy/pen/yeGRmO Might show the issue a bit clearer! Cheers!

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's great! :)